# Stack RAM and data RAM of 8085

Tags: microprocessor

Where is the Stack RAM and data RAM located in the block diagram of 8085 microprocessor ? I am unable to find it in block diagram .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They aren't part of the microprocessor. The RAM is external to this microprocessor, and is accessed over the memory bus.

Note that the 8085 does not make a distinction between "stack RAM" and "data RAM". Memory is memory.

Comment: What about ROM , is it also external to the microprocessor?

Comment: Yes, same. Only I/O is (possibly) in a different address space, everything else (and possibly I/O too) is in the 'main' address space. Which is outside the  8085 chip.